# Using PHP variable and use it in Jquery/Ajax page load request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have set up a PHP variable like this:

```
$phpurl = $_GET["url"]
```

where `url` value will be from `GET` variable query. The value of "url" will be some sort of html page link with some content like "`myContent.html`" I want to load.

How can I get this "url" value, which I have assigned to the variable "`$phpurl`"
and use it in the Ajax/Jquery page load request?

```
$('.content').load('  ** need the value of "$phpurl" to be placed here ** ');
```

Hope the question is clear. I am pretty new into programming. Thanks.

Comment: Try using $('.content').load('<?php echo $phpurl ?>'); . Or if you want to echo it directly from GET[url], just use $('.content').load('<?php echo $_GET["url"] ?>'); .

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

```
$('.content').load('<?php echo json_encode($phpurl); ?>');
```

will do

Comment: You might want to think about escaping that variable.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to take precaution to escape the value properly

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  var url = decodeURIComponent('<?php echo rawurlencode($phpurl) ?>');
</script>
```

Or you could try something like https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

```
// requires no PHP at all!
var url = $.url(window.location).attr('url');
$('.content').load(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

As a generic rule you should properly escape variables when you move them between two realms, in this case from PHP to JavaScript.

This is especially true if you don't have full control over the variable contents, such as those coming from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc.

This is a safe bet, using [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) to form a proper JavaScript value:

```
$('.content').load(<?php echo json_encode($phpurl); ?>);
```